# Distinguish synonyms from single-tag questions on the /tags page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, user-interface

When browsing the list of tags on a site, a number is shown next to each tag indicating how many questions have that tag, e.g. “[sometag](/questions/tagged/sometag) × 42”. If there is a single question with that tag, no indication is shown. If the tag is a synonym of another tag, or if the tag has no questions and is scheduled for deletion the next time the cleanup job runs, no indication is shown.

Please visually distinguish tags with a single question from tag names that are synonyms and tags that are scheduled for deletion. This is very useful information when reviewing tags.

[image: annotated /tags screenshot]

Comment: Better yet: Don't show synonyms as 'tags' in their own right: Have them displayed the same as they appear [when adding tags to the tags field](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48802429/Capture.png) on questions, with the master tag and text: 'also: **synonym1**, **synonym2**'

Comment: This is partially done now. I added the question count to tags with a single question.

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks! I think this warrants [meta-tag:status-completed]. Showing synonyms and distinguishing synonyms from about-to-be-deleted tags could be useful, but there's already a separate interface for them. Since in-use tags can be distinguished from “improper” tags, I consider my request fulfilled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling this done - I added the question count to tags with a single question, and if you're happy with that, I'm happy as well. :)